# ¿Es posible acumular objetos idénticos de un ArrayList en la misma fila de un ListView?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, listview, adapter

Tengo un proyecto donde llamo a una api que devuelve un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Mesa 1",
"productosDto": [
    {
        "id": 40,
        "name": "Croquetas",
        "image": "Imagen",
        "price": 5.0
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Croquetas",
        "image": "Imagen",
        "price": 5.0
    },
    {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Sardinas",
        "image": "Imagen",
        "price": 5.0
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Pizza Yorkeso",
        "image": "Imagen",
        "price": 6.5
    }
  ]
}
```

Y aquí enseño la llamada a la api:

```
 public void GetMesa(){

    Call<Mesa> call=mesaService.getMesa(Mesaid, "application/json");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Mesa>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Mesa> call, Response<Mesa> response) {

            for(int i=0;i< response.body().getProductosDto().size();i++)
            {

                Producto producto= new Producto(response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getId(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getName(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getImage(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getPrice());

                productosCliente.add(producto);

            }
            productoAdapter = new ProductoAdapter(MesaActivity.this, R.layout.adapter_producto, productosCliente);
            listaProductosCliente.setAdapter(productoAdapter);
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Mesa> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("response", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Como podéis ver, recojo objetos de tipo "Producto", los introduzco en un ArrayList (productoCliente) y los añado a un ListView (listaProductosCliente) a través de un adapter personalizado.

Todo funciona correctamente y esto es lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí viene mi duda:

Quiero mostrar todos los objetos (Producto) que tengan el mismo nombre en la misma fila del ListView y añadir un TextView que indique cuál es la cantidad de objetos iguales acumulados. Es decir, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible?

También añado el código de mi adapter por si acaso:

```
public class ProductoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
int itemLayout;
List<Producto> productos;

public ProductoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Producto> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    itemLayout = resource;
    productos = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

    name.setText(productos.get(position).getName());

    String priceSTR = String.valueOf(productos.get(position).getPrice());
    price.setText(priceSTR);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos y perdonad las molestias. Ya está editado!

Comment: Si lo resolviste, porque no agregaste una respuesta contando como lo resolviste? Tal vez no explicaste tu problema lo suficiente, o tal vez justo tu pregunta quedo tapada por otras...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podés hacer es agregar un nuevo campo "quantity" a la clase "Producto". Y cuando cargas la lista "productosCliente" verificar si el producto ya existe:

1. Si existe, en lugar de agregar una nueva fila, sumas la cantidad.
2. Si NO existe, ahí lo agregas como lo venías haciendo.

Después en el adapter miras si la cantidad es mayor a 1, entonces mostrar el label "X2", "X3", etc.

Un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer sería:

```
for(int i=0;i< response.body().getProductosDto().size();i++)
{
    String nombreProducto = response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getName();
    Producto productoExistente = null;
    
    //buscamos si ya existe el producto en la lista
    for(int pi=0;pi<productosCliente.size();pi++){
        Producto productoCliente = productosCliente.get(pi);
        if(productoCliente.getName().equals(nombreProducto)){
            //si existe, lo asignamos a productoExistente, y dejamos de buscar
            productoExistente = productoCliente;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(productoExistente != null){
        //si el producto ya estaba en la lista, sumamos su cantidad
        productoExistente.setCantidad(productoExistente.getCantidad() + 1);
    }else{
        //si el producto aún no está en la lista, lo agregamos
        Producto producto= new Producto(response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getId(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getName(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getImage(),response.body().getProductosDto().get(i).getPrice());
    
        productosCliente.add(producto);
    }

}
```

Te recomiendo no copiar el código, sino tratar de entenderlo y escribirlo usando los nombres de las clases y variables que usaste.